# enumerative combinatorics and geometric series

Tags: combinatorics

So, I'm going to take an enumerative combinatorics class this upcoming semester.  I began reading about it and came across and interesting example, but I am not sure how they arrive at their final answer. The example is in in the image I included.  I don't know how they determined the equations for $c_n$.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay so I don't think my picture was included so I am just going to include a link to the pdf and the example number.  The example number is 1.1.5 in this link http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the following statement?

$\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 0} \alpha^n x^n = \frac{1}{1 - \alpha x}$

This is nothing but the sum of a geometric series. For a derivation, see 
[Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Comment: No I was asking about the part using the product of power series.  Then c_n = part

Answer (score 0):

This is standard
manipulation of power series,
and you will have to
become comfortable
with doing this.

You want to get the power series for
$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)(1-ax)
$.

In this case,
you separate the two sums,
shift an index of summation,
and recombine the two series.

Here are the details.

$\begin{array}\\
P(x)
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)(1-ax)\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)-ax\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)
\qquad\text{distribute the sum}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)-\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n+1}x^{n+1}\right)
\qquad\text{bring }ax \text{ into the sum}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n}x^{n}\right)
\qquad\text{shift the index of summation}\\
&=1+\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^nx^n\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n}x^{n}\right)
\qquad\text{split the first term so the indices match}\\
&=1
\qquad\text{like magic, the two series cancel each other out}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you for this, I had this worked out.  What I wasn’t sure about was the part in the example where the determined the c_n = a^n - a(a^(n -1)), n >= 1

Comment: I did that by having two identical sums cancelling each other out. If you want, I can redo it by combining terms, though I might not get to it till tomorrow.

Comment: Sure and no rush!